# HP Omen 17 touchpad not showing in xinput list

Tags: system-installation, touchpad

Brand new HP Omen 017, installed dual W11 Ubuntu 20.04

The trackpad is not working.

When I run `xinput list` I get:

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELECOM TrackBall Mouse DEFT Pro TrackBall id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PRiMAX HP OMEN 17 KBM Mouse               id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PRiMAX HP OMEN 17 KBM Consumer Control    id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ELECOM TrackBall Mouse DEFT Pro TrackBall id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ELECOM TrackBall Mouse DEFT Pro TrackBall Consumer Control    id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ELECOM TrackBall Mouse DEFT Pro TrackBall System Control  id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wide Vision HD Camera: HP Wi           id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ PRiMAX HP OMEN 17 KBM Keyboard            id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ PRiMAX HP OMEN 17 KBM Keypad              id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ PRiMAX HP OMEN 17 KBM Wireless Radio Control  id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ PRiMAX HP OMEN 17 KBM Consumer Control    id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

[In Windows 11 the trackpad works fine, and device manager reports as Elan Precision Touchpad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SjyP.jpg)

Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: Add `lsusb` command output